# jQuery ajax crossdomain for Google fonts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, cross-domain

I been trying to get the CSS result content from the following link.

```
 https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?&family=Cabin+Sketch:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i
```

I tried multiple methods of $.get, $.post, $.ajax
Ive used crossDomain: true, dataTypes, headers and so on..

Issues i picked up were, Mime mismatch, cors - same domain issues etc..

how can i get the content of this TEXT/CSS link with $.ajax || $.get || $.post or if you have a better method I'm all ears.

Comment: why? anyway, the only fix if a server doesn't allow CORS is to use **your server** to *proxy* the request

Comment: I solved this with the long method of posting to a php file and then doing a filegetcontents()..